# How to list all the model monitoring job on vertex ai given the display name?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have enabled the model monitoring job for my endpoint on the first pipeline run. For the first run, the first version of the model is created for which monitoring is enabled.
Now when I rerun the pipeline, a new version of the model will be created, in that case how to enable the model monitoring job for the new model version through python SDK?

Or will it be enabled automatically given that both models are deployed to the same endpoint?

Comment: Are you running the same pipeline again? You can refer to this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/model_monitoring/model_monitoring.ipynb) to create your monitoring job. Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: This link is useful if you run the pipeline for the first run, now my endpoint is already up and running and you run the pipeline again. In this case, a new model version will be deployed. Now, instead of re-creating the monitoring job I want to enable the previously created monitoring job for my current model version.